# Event to keep the overlay highlighted even during right-click menu traversing

Tags: css, ajax, d3.js, svg, dom-events

I have a scenario similar to the following where an overlay detects the mouse hover, which expands the clickable-area of the square. I have a right click menu to be bound to it and with the following approach of `mouseleave`, the overlay is not highlighted when the right click menu is displayed - because mouseleave is triggered.

How to keep the overlay highlighted even during right click? Or can I use different events than mouseleave and mouseover?

```js
var overlay = d3.select("#overlay");
var mouseOver = function() {
  return overlay.style("opacity", "0.5");
}
var mouseLeave = function() {
  return overlay.style("opacity", "0");
}
overlay.on("mouseover", mouseOver)
  .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.js"></script>
<p>Hover over the square</p><br>
<svg id="canvas" height="300" width="300">
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="black" />
  <rect id="overlay" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="blue" style="opacity:0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Please show the full not-working code - including the right click handling.  We are happy to help fix problems with your code, but people are unlikely to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding a constraint to the mouseleave function. That is, to check if the right click menu is triggered and continue is the menu is not triggered.

For that, I added a class during right-click-menu display and removed it when the menu is hiding and check the class during mouseleave.

The following needs improvement, but the basic idea is demonstrated.

```js
var overlay = d3.select("#overlay");
var mouseOver = function() {
  return overlay.style("opacity", "0.5");
}
var mouseLeave = function() {
  return overlay.classed("overlay-clicked") ? null : overlay.style("opacity", "0");
}
var menuOn = function() {
  return overlay.classed("overlay-clicked", true);
}
var menuOff = function() {
  return overlay.classed("overlay-clicked", false).style("opacity", "0");
}
d3.select("body").on("click", menuOff);
overlay.on("mouseover", mouseOver)
  .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
  .on("contextmenu", menuOn);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.js"></script>
<p>Hover over the square</p>
<br>
<svg id="canvas" height="300" width="300">
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="black" />
  <rect id="overlay" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="blue" style="opacity:0" />
</svg>
```